# several methods to same instance - DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

Sorry if this is too simple. I'm looking for a way to make my `ruby` code dry : I want to call a number of methods on the same instance variable `@var = Model.new(param)` :

```
@var.method1
@var.method2
@var.method3
...
```

Is it possible to use the `send` method to write one line of code ? Btw, is it possible to call a block on `Model.new` to produce some more concise code ?

Comment: Do you want method chaining ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you build `method1`, `method2`, etc. such that they return the instance itself using `self`, you can build a chainable interface. For example:

```
class Foo
  def method1
    # do something
    self
  end

  def method2
    # do something
    self
  end

  def method3
    # do something
    self
  end

  # more methods...
end

@var = Foo.new

@var.method1.method2.method3

# or if this gets too long

@var.method1
    .method2
    .method3
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe that DRY should be used to make your code more maintainable, and more readable. I *don't* think it should be used to shorten the number of characters you type, or show-off your code acrobatics.

Both @Arup's and @p11y's solutions are great, within a context, but as a general rule (before knowing anything about your class or methods), I believe that writing

```
@var.method1
@var.method2
@var.method3
```

is more readable and maintainable than writing either

```
%i[method1 method2 method3].each(&@var.method(:send))
```

(you need to be fluent in advanced ruby to understand this)

or

```
@var.method1
    .method2
    .method3
```

(again the vanishing act is more confusing to the future reader than helpful)

Always think about who will read your code in 6 months, and what will be the clearest way for him to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

Do as below :

```
%i[method1 method2 method3].each { |m| @var.send(m) }
```

If you want to make it more short,use :

```
%i[method1 method2 method3].each(&@var.method(:send))
```

Comment: `@var.method(:send)` you mean?

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote my original answer, I missed the last sentence in your question:

> Btw, is it possible to call a block on `Model.new` to produce some more concise code ?

And the answer to this question is YES. This pattern is a builder pattern, which is implemented in several gems in ruby (such as [`tire`](https://github.com/karmi/retire/blob/master/lib/tire/index.rb#L8)).

The pattern states that the `initialize` method receives a block, which is run in the context of the created object, using `instance_eval`. If the block receives a parameter, the instance object is passed to it instead of changing the block's scope:

```
class Model
  def initialize(name, &block)
    @name = name
    block.arity < 1 ? instance_eval(&block) : block.call(self) if block_given?
  end

  def method1
    # something
  end
  def method2
    # something
  end
  def method3
    # something
  end
end
```

And its usage will be something either like this:

```
@var = Model.new('model') do
         method1
         method2
         method3
       end
```

or, alternatively:

```
@var = Model.new('model') do |m|
         m.method1
         m.method2
         m.method3
       end
```